# How to apply a predefined CSS class in PHP

Tags: php, css

I would like to apply a CSS class to my output that is defined in a .css file. In the test snippet below I'm using the class, but it is not applied. Do I need to reference the file in some way or how do I apply it?

```
function dyc_product_archive_description(){
    if ( is_product_category( 'mycategory' ) ) {

        echo '<h1 class="product_title">' . 'mycategory' .'</h1>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually [CSS is included in `head` section](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) and it is part of generated page's code (not always in place where you want to use it. Without knowing your project we cannot tell where exactly you have to put it, just can suggest using browser's code review and inspection tool you can verify that CSS was included at all, or not.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please update your question with more details or it will be closed and/or downvoted. Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks, the class is defined in a file outside of this auto-generated page, thus I cannot add it to the head section. I can of course generate inline css but that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: We definitely don't know how do you include CSS in your project. You didn't tell us if you're using any framework or CMS, just pasted some random part of code and expects us to imagine the rest, that won't work. Please add more details. but first, debug what you have already to find why these styles are not accessed, we can not do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

There are several problems you may have:

## This is a function

Since the code you have shown here is a function, you will need to make sure that you see what you think you see. Is this function called at all? Do some action, like writing a line in the logs as the first action of the function and see whether that's created.

If the function is not called, then the class is not applied by it.

## We have a conditional

Now, if the function has been executed in the previous check, then move the behavior inside the conditional and see whether it is still happening. If not, then research your condition to find out whether it's correct. If it's incorrect, fix it. If your data is incorrect, fix it.

## The class is added to the tag

Check the page-source of your browser. If the tag has the class, then the class is applied, but its styling is not. If the tag does not has the class, then either it is not generated by this function, or the class might have been removed by some Javascript. Check other instances of this tag's creation and see whether you were looking at the wrong place, see whether the class is inside the tag at all. If the tag is not inside the tag, then fix your code so that the class will be inside the tag. If it's already inside the tag, then see the next step.

## Make sure that your CSS is applied

You have a styling, possibly in another file. Test that styling in the browser, by adding it to the class you have using the Dev Tools. If the styling is applied then, then check the inactive styles on your tag. If among the inactive styles you find the one which you intended, then you have a CSS priority issue. If not, then the styling you have is never loaded, in which case you need to load it.

Comment: Thanks. The function and conditional is called and the tag applied. The css is not loaded, that's what I'm asking for. How do I load it?

Comment: @KnudsenAllan you will need to create a link tag, specifying its rel attribute to be stylesheet and providing the correct href, see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Answer (score -1):

Just realized this was much easier than I thought by just adding:

```
echo '<link rel="StyleSheet" href="https://example.com/csspath?ver=1.0.20" media="all" />';
```